# Discord Bot | DiscordJS | Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

so I've been working on a Discord bot using the Discord.JS library and I've ran into a problem. Pretty sure the problem is more related to Javascript versus Discord.JS so I'll ask here and hope for some assistance.

I have a file called commandManager.js that holds all my basic command functions. One of them being autoloading the commands from the /commands/ folder and assigning them to an array based off of their category (which is specified in the command via exports).

```
global.userCommands = {};
global.modCommands = {};
global.adminCommands = {};
global.ownerCommands = {};

exports.init = function(bot)
{
    fs.readdir("./commands/", (error, files) =>
    {
        if (error)
        {
            logger.error(error);
        }

        files.forEach(file =>
        {
            let commandFile = require(`../commands/${file}`);
            let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
            if (commandFile.info.category == "User")
            {
                userCommands[commandName] = commandFile;
            }
            else if (commandFile.info.category == "Mod")
            {
                modCommands[commandName] = commandFile;
            }
            else if (commandFile.info.category == "Admin")
            {
                adminCommands[commandName] = commandFile;
            }
            else if (commandFile.info.category == "Owner")
            {
                ownerCommands[commandName] = commandFile;
            }
            else
            {
                logger.warn("Could not add the command " + commandName + " to any of the categories");
            }
        });

        logger.info("Loaded " + files.length + " command(s)");
    });
}
```

Then after this I can use a command in the actual bot on message bit which I did as following:

```
exports.run = function(bot, msg)
{   
    const args = msg.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const cleanCommand = command.slice(config.prefix.length);

    if (msg.author.bot)
    {
        return;
    }   
    else if (msg.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) 
    {
        return;
    }   
    else if (has.call(userCommands, cleanCommand))
    {
        msg.reply("user");
    }
    else if (has.call(modCommands, cleanCommand))
    {

    }
    else if (has.call(adminCommands, cleanCommand))
    {

    }
    else if (has.call(ownerCommands, cleanCommand))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        msg.reply(`that command does not even exist! You can say ${config.prefix}help for a list of commands!`);
    }
}
```

So when I say the command for example "ping" it SHOULD reply with msg.reply("user") but instead it says it doesn't exist whatsoever. I declared has as a global like this incase you were curious.

```
global.has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

If you'd like to see the command it is as follows:

```
exports.info =
{
    name: "Ping",
    permission: 10,
    category: "User",
    about: "Makes the bot respond with pong, useful to see if the bot is working."
};

exports.run = function(msg)
{
    msg.channel.send("Pong!");
}
```

Any tips, reference, examples, or just plain spoon feeding is 100% welcome. Also, if you'd like to maybe share some better techniques for doing what I'm doing please let me know as I'm just a beginner with JS.

Comment: Why not `userCommands[cleanCommand]` ?? And what should category be good for?

Comment: Well, category is the idea I had for separating them if I were to do a commands list later in the future. And not sure why not to be honest with you. Any better ideas for category then or what I could do instead to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

*The following is completely opinion based...*

I bet you want to use nested commands too e.g. *play music* and *play video*, so in my opinion a command tree would be the way to go here. With that theres also no need to parse the commands from the folder, instead we can have a more independent structure. The starting file would look like this:

```
module.exports = (sub, exit) => ({ 
  //a global handler applied to all commands:
  [sub]:(user)=>"Hi there!",
  //a main exit point ( if a command cannot be found)
  [exit]:{
    run:(user,command)=>"Sorry ${command} doesnt exist"
  },
  //commands
  play: {
    //the following is applied to "play whatever"
    [exit]:{
      desc:"a random command",
      run:(user, ...args) => args.join(" "),
      category:"random"
    },
    //the following is applied to all subcommands
    [sub]:(user)=> user.admin?"start playing":new Error("you must be an admin"),

    //the subcommands
    video:{
      //sub sub commands maybe
      [exit]: {
        info: "to play videos",
        run(user, videoname)=> videoname+".mp4"
      }
   },
   //one can also use require here
   whatever: require("./whatever.js")(sub,exit)
 });
```

With this pattern were able to apply code to a whole bunch of commands ( through `[sub]` ) and commands can be run with subcommands etc ( through the `[exit]`). Now lets implement the routing:

```
const exit = Symbol("exit"), sub = Symbol("sub");
//requiring the above tree
const routes = require("./commands.js")(exit,sub);
//implementing the router:
function route(tree, user, params ){
  var res;
  //the [sub] implementation
  if( tree[sub] ){
    res = tree[sub]( user, ...params);
    if( res instanceof Error ){
       //if an error applied exit now
       return "An error occured:"+res;
    }
  }

  if( tree[ params[0] ] ){
    return res + "\n" + route( tree[ params[0] , user, params.slice(1) );
  } else {
    return res + " \n" + tree[exit].run(user, params);
  }
}
```

So to get it running:

```
msg.reply(
  route(
   routes,
   {admin:true, /*...*/ },
   msg.content.split(" ")
 )
);
```

You can still extend that with per category handlers etc.